# Explicit Razor expressions not working in @foreach output model property and concatenate with text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.1

I would like to create the following markup

```
     <tr onclick="toggle(110)" data-order-id-110=110><td>foo</td></tr>
```

the important part is the [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) `data-order-id-110=110`. For every item in my model the id (here 110) should be written as a data-attribute that includes the `id` in this case `110`.

According to my understanding of [Explicit Razor expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#explicit-razor-expressions)

> Any content within the @() parenthesis is evaluated and rendered to the output.

it should be good enough to write

```
// this code
data-order-id-@(@order.Id)=@order.Id

// actual returns 
data-order-id@(@order.id)="1"

// expected
data-order-id-1="1"
```

So besides  `@(@)` i also tried `@{=@}` like this

```
 data-order-id-@(@order.Id)=@order.Id
 data-order-id-@{=@order.Id}=@order.Id
```

Both did not work, see below.

#### My code

I tried

```
  <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(@order.Id)" 
      data-order-id-@(order.Id)=@order.Id>
```

which returns

```
 <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(1)" data-order-id-@(order.id)="1">
       .....
        </tr>
```

and also tried

```
 @foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
 {
     <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(@order.Id)" data-order-id-@{=@order.Id}=@order.Id>
            <td>@order.Id</td>
            <td>@order.CustomerId</td>
            <td>@order.OrderDate</td>
     </tr> 
 }
```

#### The html output

```
 <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(1)" data-order-id-@{="1}=1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>26.08.2021 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see insteald of `data-order-id-1=1` the string `data-order-id-@{="1}=1` is created.

- expected: `data-order-id-1=1`
- actual: `data-order-id-@{="1}=1`

Others have mentioned to us `@:` but this does not work

#### Installed version

```
dotnet --info
```

returns

```
 .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
      Version:   3.1.118     Commit:    42170158ee

 Host (useful for support):
      Version: 3.1.18        Commit:  5d3919d34e

 .NET Core SDKs installed:
      3.1.118 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

 .NET Core runtimes installed:
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 
      Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.18
```

The assemply for `class MvcServiceCollectionExtensions` is

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
         , Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral
         , PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
         // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll
#endregion
```

#### Questions

What do i need to concatenate an html data-attribute with a property from a model

Comment: try change @(@order.id) to  @Html.Raw(order.id) it should be fine

Comment: I think you should replace `data-order-id-@{=@order.Id}=@order.Id` with `data-order-id-@(order.Id)=@order.Id`

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ this i tried as well see update above

Comment: I don't see why `data-order-id-@order.Id=@order.Id` doesn't work?

Comment: @daremachine: 
This `<tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(@order.Id)" data-order-id-@Html.Raw(order.id)=@order.Id>` return this markup  `<tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(1)" data-order-id-@html.raw(order.id)="1"> .... </tr>`

Comment: @DavidG this code `<tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(@order.Id)" data-order-id-@order.Id=@order.Id>` creates this markup `<tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(1)" data-order-id-@order.id="1">`

Comment: you have something wrong with razor :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this

```
@foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
{
    string attribute = "data-order-id-"+@order.Id;
    <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(@order.Id)" @(attribute)=@order.Id>
}
```

This returns this markup

```
 <tr onclick="toggleOrderDetails(1)" data-order-id-1="1">
       ....
 </tr>
```